# Does Rails 4 allow ruby code in a .JS view, in rails 3 it was required to have .erb.js in the filename

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb, respond-to

Does Rails 4 allow ruby code in a .JS view, in rails 3 it was required to have .erb.js in the filename

```
  def test
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { Rails.logger.info "in JS handler" }
    end
  end



/app/views/users/test.erb.js <== no longer works in rails 4
```

and

```
/app/views/users/test.js <== still works in rails 4 but does it allow ruby inside this file?
```

Comment: Surely you mean `.js.erb` ?

Comment: @ThongKuah correct overlooked this every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file must be named `test.js.erb` to include Ruby code in it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was file had to be named

```
file.js.erb
```

not

```
file.erb.js
```